# Is my rephrasing of this purpose clause correct?

Tags: grammar-choice, gerund

Suppose I have a sentence:

> *"Hercules reliquit viam ut Megaram peteret."*

If I want to rephrase the purpose clause using the gerund / gerundive; would it be correct to write the following?

> *"Hercules viam reliquit ad petendum Megaram."*

Should I even be using the gerund / gerundive here?

Answer (score 5):

Although the gerund can be used to express purpose, it's not allowed in this case because of the direct object *Megaram*. As stated in *[Allen and Greenough's Latin Grammar](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/gerund-and-gerundive)*:

> The accusative of the gerund with a preposition never takes a direct
>   object in classic Latin.

They provide more information on the correct usage as follows:

> **503.** When the gerund would have an object in the accusative, the Gerundive is generally used instead. The gerundive agrees with its
>   noun, which takes the case that the gerund would have had.
>
> ***parātiōrēs ad omnia perīcula subeunda*** (B. G. 1.5)
>  readier to undergo all dangers
>
> Here ***subeunda*** agrees with ***perīcula***, which is itself governed
>   by ***ad***. The (inadmissible) construction with the gerund would be
>   ***ad subeundum perīcula***; ***ad*** governing the gerund, and the gerund governing the accusative ***perīcula***. For details, see §§ 504 - 507,
>   below.

Your sentence could be expressed with the gerundive as follows:

> Hercules viam reliquit ad Megaram petendam.